# std::map compare function and NULL

Tags: c++, stl

I've written a compare function for a std::map so I can have custom key types.

```
std::map<GGString *, GGObject *, GGDictionaryMapCompare> _map;
```

...

```
class GGDictionaryMapCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(GGString * lhs, GGString * rhs)
    {
        return strcmp(lhs->str(), rhs->str()) < 0;
    }
};
```

Code that adds elements:

```
GGObject *GGDictionary::addKeyObject(GGString *theKey, GGObject *theObject)
{
    if (theKey == NULL || theObject == NULL)
        return NULL;

    _map.insert(std::pair<GGString *, GGObject *>(theKey, theObject));

    return theObject;
}
```

Code that is causing the crash:

```
GGObject *GGDictionary::objectForKey(GGString *theKey)
{
    if (theKey == NULL)
        return NULL;

    std::map<GGString *, GGObject *, GGDictionaryMapCompare>::iterator ii = _map.find(theKey);
    if (ii == _map.end())
    return NULL;

    return GGAutoRelease(ii->second);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
#0  0x00009f15 in GGString::str()
#1  0x0004a4c4 in GGDictionaryMapCompare::operator()(GGString*, GGString*)
#2  0x0004a3d3 in std::_Rb_tree<GGString*, std::pair<GGString* const, GGObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<GGString* const, GGObject*> >, GGDictionaryMapCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<GGString* const, GGObject*> > >::find(GGString* const&)
#3  0x00049b04 in std::map<GGString*, GGObject*, GGDictionaryMapCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<GGString* const, GGObject*> > >::find(GGString* const&)
#4  0x00048ec9 in GGDictionary::objectForKey(GGString*)
```

The issue is that the lhs is coming in NULL. I never insert a NULL into the map, so this should not be happening. Any idea why? Or am I just doing the compare function wrong? I can protect against getting NULL, but it seems like something is wrong and I don't want to cure a symptom and not the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Show where do you add elements.

Comment: Could you post some code about how you're using this, and/or how you're adding elements to the map?  I could try to reproduce the problem.  I don't see any obvious issues with that code so perhaps it's something weird in the implementation.

Comment: If you GGString is coming in `NULL` its the insertion of a `NULL` *key* you're looking for, NOT a `NULL` *value*

Comment: I've added some new code, but inserting NULL keys or values is protected against. This is the only function that inserts keys/values.

Comment: You're not checking the `theKey` argument for NULL. map::find will use your comparator.

Comment: Just added code to check for key being NULL and that doesn't fix the problem, still crashes in the same place.

Comment: What does `GGAutoRelease` do?

Comment: Are you sure the pointer is really NULL and not just invalid?

Comment: Are you sure you don't modify `_map` anywhere else, e.g. with an unintentional `_map[foo]` where `foo` is `NULL`?

Comment: Yep, I check all my code, add there is only that one place.

Comment: `GGString *` is usually a sign of a bad design. There are very few cases where it is useful to distinguish between an empty container and no container. As a side benefit, `std::map<GGString, GGObject *>` would not have these problems.

Answer (score 5):

In this code:

```
GGObject *GGDictionary::objectForKey(GGString *theKey)
{
    std::map<GGString *, GGObject *, GGDictionaryMapCompare>::iterator ii = _map.find(theKey);
    if (ii == _map.end())
        return NULL;

    return GGAutoRelease(ii->second);
}
```

You aren't checking whether `theKey` is `NULL`.  Accordingly, when the comparator is invoked on `theKey` and any element of the `map`, you will dereference `NULL`.

To fix this, try adding in a `NULL` check:

```
GGObject *GGDictionary::objectForKey(GGString *theKey)
{
    if (theKey == NULL) return NULL;

    std::map<GGString *, GGObject *, GGDictionaryMapCompare>::iterator ii = _map.find(theKey);
    if (ii == _map.end())
        return NULL;

    return GGAutoRelease(ii->second);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Adding that code doesn't fix the problem, still crashes in the same place.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat- Are you sure you're passing in a `NULL` pointer and not a garbage pointer?  Can you let us know what the bad pointer is?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the key compare function should be revised to something like this:

```
bool operator()(const GGString *&lhs, const GGString *&rhs)
{
    if (lhs == NULL || rhs == NULL)
    {
       return false;
    }
    return strcmp(lhs->str(), rhs->str()) < 0;
}
```

Basically I'm thinking the parameters should be const references, and also that the function should protect against dereferencing NULL pointers

Comment: It makes comparisons slower and probably cures the symptom.

Comment: Supporting `null` might be a good idea, but this function doesn't give a strict weak ordering. For any value `a`, `comp(a, null)` and `comp(null, a)` are both false, which means that all values are equivalent to `null`, and therefore all values are equivalent to each other.

Comment: Instead, do this: `if (rhs == NULL) return false; if (lhs == NULL) return true;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the crash happens when accessing NULL? You are storing pointers in the map; is it possible that you deleted one of the pointers after storing it in the map? Something like this:

```
dict->addKeyObject( key1, obj1 );
delete key1; // now dict has a pointer to deleted key1
dict->addKeyObject( key2, obj2 ); // now dict will compare key2 to key1, causing crash
```